# Show control conditionally in Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I have this custom post type with two meta fields that I need to show as toggle controls (`RestrictControl` and `SubscribeControl`) in the `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` sidebar in the Gutenberg editor. The thing is that I only want to show `SubscribeControl` when `RestrictControl` is set. This is the code I've got currently but it's not working. When I toggle `RestrictControl` on and off both controls are always displayed.

Any ideas?

```
let RestrictControl = ({ restrict, onUpdateRestrict }) => (
    <ToggleControl
        label={ __( 'Restrict viewing?' ) }
        checked={ restrict }
        onChange={ restrict => onUpdateRestrict( restrict ) }
    />
);

let SubscribeControl = ({ subscribe, onUpdateSubscribe }) => (
    <ToggleControl
        label={ __( 'Add to newsletter?' ) }
        checked={ subscribe }
        onChange={ subscribe => onUpdateSubscribe( subscribe ) }
    />
);

const OptionsPanel = () => {
    const postType = select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType();
    if ( 'custom_type' !== postType ) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
            name='options'
            title={ __( 'Options' ) }
            className='options-panel'
        >
            <RestrictControl />
            { restrict && (
                <SubscribeControl />
            ) }
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    );
}

registerPlugin( 'options-panel', {
    render: OptionsPanel,
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 main issues in your code:

1. What is that `restrict` in your `OptionsPanel` component? Where and how you defined it?
2. Both the `onUpdateRestrict` and `onUpdateSubscribe` are not functions, so clicking on the toggle controls will result in a JavaScript error.

And if you can show your complete code, I can probably help you *fix* your code. However, I suggest you to try the [`compose` package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-compose/) to build the `OptionsPanel` component because doing it that way can greatly help reduce the source and make things quite easy for us.

#### So with the `compose` package, the steps are:

***Note: I'm using these two meta keys: `restrict_viewing` and `subscribe_to_news`, so be sure to change them to the correct ones.*** (I.e. Use the proper meta keys.)

1. Load all WordPress dependencies:

   ```js
   import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
   import { ToggleControl } from '@wordpress/components';
   import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
   import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
   import { withSelect, withDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
   import { compose } from '@wordpress/compose';
   ```
2. Create the primary component which basically simply renders the plugin/sidebar panel plus the two toggle controls (the `RestrictControl` & `SubscribeControl` in the question).

   ```js
   function OptionsPanelComponent( {
       // These props are passed by applyWithSelect(). (see step #3)
       currentPostType, // current post type
       restrictViewing, // current state of the meta restrict_viewing
       subscribeToNews, // current state of the meta subscribe_to_news
       // And these are passed by applyWithDispatch(). (see step #4)
       onUpdateRestrict,  // function which updates the meta restrict_viewing
       onUpdateSubscribe, // function which updates the meta subscribe_to_news
   } ) {
       if ( 'custom_type' !== currentPostType ) {
           return null;
       }

       return (
           <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
               name="options"
               title={ __( 'Options' ) }
               className="options-panel"
           >
               <ToggleControl
                   label={ __( 'Restrict viewing?' ) }
                   checked={ restrictViewing }
                   onChange={ onUpdateRestrict }
               />
               { restrictViewing && (
                   <ToggleControl
                       label={ __( 'Add to newsletter?' ) }
                       checked={ subscribeToNews }
                       onChange={ onUpdateSubscribe }
                   />
               ) }
           </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
       );
   }
   ```
3. Use [`wp.data.withSelect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-data/#withSelect) to 'select'/retrieve data from the current post (that's being edited) and pass the data to the above component (`OptionsPanelComponent`).

   *Note: The `select` is always passed to the function and that `select` is equivalent to `wp.data.select`.*

   ```js
   const applyWithSelect = withSelect( ( select ) => {
       const {
           getEditedPostAttribute,
           getCurrentPostType
       } = select( 'core/editor' );

       const meta = getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' );

       return {
           currentPostType: getCurrentPostType(),
           restrictViewing: meta.restrict_viewing,
           subscribeToNews: meta.subscribe_to_news,
       };
   } );
   ```
4. Use [`wp.data.withDispatch`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-data/#withDispatch) to define the functions for updating the post data and pass the functions to the component in step #2 above (`OptionsPanelComponent`).

   *Note: The `dispatch` is always passed to the function and that `dispatch` is equivalent to `wp.data.dispatch`.*

   ```js
   const applyWithDispatch = withDispatch( ( dispatch ) => {
       const { editPost } = dispatch( 'core/editor' );

       return {
           onUpdateRestrict( restrict ) {
               const meta = { restrict_viewing: restrict };
               editPost( { meta } );
           },
           onUpdateSubscribe( subscribe ) {
               const meta = { subscribe_to_news: subscribe };
               editPost( { meta } );
           },
       };
   } );
   ```
5. Then finally, use `wp.compose.compose()` to 'compose'/wrap all the three components above (they might be defined using `function` or `const`, but they really are components). And this 'composed' component will be the one we pass as the `render` callback for `wp.plugins.registerPlugin`.

   ```js
   const OptionsPanel = compose(
       applyWithSelect,
       applyWithDispatch
   )( OptionsPanelComponent );

   registerPlugin( 'options-panel', {
       render: OptionsPanel,
   } );
   ```

### Full Code I used for testing purposes

You can find it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ej0cx6bldxojsc/wpse-367355.zip?dl=0&file_subpath=%2Fwpse-367355%2Fsrc%2Findex.js), or you can download [the full plugin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ej0cx6bldxojsc/wpse-367355.zip?dl=1) which I created based on [this example](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/tree/master/01-basic-esnext).

And I have tried & tested that on WordPress 5.4.1 with the default `post` post type with the two meta keys mentioned earlier in this answer.

### Alternate Solution

If you *don't* want to use `compose()`, then you can try [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ej0cx6bldxojsc/wpse-367355.zip?dl=0&file_subpath=%2Fwpse-367355%2Fsrc%2Findex-alt.js). But I'm adding that just because I thought it would be useful to myself in the future. :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `wp.compose.compose` and not `wp.data.compose`. I'll correct that later.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm pretty much a newbie in Gutenberg development and your code and explanation helped me to better understand the inner workings of it.

Comment: You're welcome! And I'm actually also still learning Gutenberg, so it's good to see useful questions like this on WPSE. :) Btw, I've corrected the typo and also revised the plugin, just in case you're interested in checking what changed. ;)